# Is it faster to write HTML code to a web page by hand, or to use jQuery (or plain ol' Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's an example page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WEB PAGE TITLE</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Would it be better (performance-wise) to write out the body like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="element"></div>
</body>
```

Or to have jQuery do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(){
   $('html').append('<body />');
   $('body').append('<div id="element" />');
};
```

Comment: I think the answer is pretty obvious - without JavaScript.

Comment: Surely the first way. It would be odd if it's faster through JavaScript, since HTML is meant to create the initial DOM. Moreover, there is no reason to put the markup in the logic.

Comment: Is it faster for you to walk one block to the store, or to have someone else drive from across town to pick you up and drive you to the store?

Comment: Why would you do it with JavaScript? Is the HTML code dynamic, i.e. is it populated with external data (e.g. database, JSON)?

Comment: Not to mention if there isn't a <body> tag, one gets created for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is 100% always better to write the HTML directly, for more than just performance reasons.

Talking strictly performance, if you write the body directly it is loaded much quicker. If you use JavaScript (jQuery, etc.), it won't be processed until most of the HTML is read, blah blah so it'll be much (relatively) slower.

Also, if you use JavaScript to write that content, if a user has JavaScript disabled they will see nothing. Not cool. You always want to go the progressive enhancement route, which is basically get everything working at a basic level without JavaScript, than add JavaScript to enhance that functionality when it is available.

Answer (score 1):

The markup approach would be faster. Not only do you not need to parse javascript, the browser does not need to wait until the ready() event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

of course without JavaScript/JQuery the rendering is faster. Also the data is a little bit less.

Answer (score 1):

There's not necessarily a "right" answer here, but I'll weigh in.

Avoid building HTML in JavaScript except when your business model requires it (e.g. building out DOM elements in response to an Ajax query).  The primary reason for this is that it's more difficult to support/modify HTML built in JavaSCript (typically).  Also, what if your user has JavaScript disabled for some reason?  It's good to have your site degrade as gracefully as possible in that scenario, if you're building your core structure in JS your site will be non-op.

Beyond that, a simple DOM structure will render much more quickly than one built in JS.

Cheers